# Pop-up dialog doesnt work within html() function

Tags: jquery, popup

I have a div tag which will dynamically be filled with a dialog.

```
<div id="f2"></div>
```

Now,in my form submit function,i give

```
$("#f2").html("<a href='#noncustomer' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='pop'>Thank you for your information. You will receive a call as soon as a representative is available</a>");
```

But, the problem is, the pop up window doesnt display. It just shows the content as a mere text..

Can someone tell me how to make the pop up appear?

Comment: Where is the code for the 'popup'?  You're only passing text to the #f2 element.

Comment: i think you are looking for a modal

Comment: @Trevor <a href='#noncustomer' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='pop'> .. This displays a popup right?

Comment: Where in the code do you think a popup window would be opened? The call to `.html()` just dumps HTML into that `<div>`.

Comment: @hari: uh, no... why do you think that would display a popup? That's just a piece of markup.

Comment: Oh my god. I saw in a website that u can use a tag with data-transition as pop and data-rel as dialog to display a pop-up.. Can you give me the right procedure for it?

Comment: THe dialog doesn't display when you click the a link within the #f2 div? You will have to make the a tag open a dialog when you click it.  Since the a tag is dynamically added, you will have to use delegate or live to attach a click handler.

Comment: i think you are looking something like the jQuery UI [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) `<a href='#noncustomer' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='pop'> ` doesn't make a popup appear unless you have some javascript code written to show pop up...

Comment: Are you looking for the alert function? alert('text');

Comment: @Trevor: alert just displays it in browser format. I want it to look cool using jquery themes

Comment: Modal is what ou are looking for.  Facebox is a nice modal system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the facebox modal plugin http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are in need of a simple jQuery modal plugin.  You can try:

- [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)
- [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)

For SimpleModal, after setting the HTML for `#f2`, simply call the `.modal()` method on it and it will display the content as a modal popup:

```
$("#f2").html("<a href='#noncustomer' data-rel='dialog' data-transition='pop'>Thank you for your information. You will receive a call as soon as a representative is available</a>");
$("#f2").modal();
```

You will probably want to include the following style in your CSS to dim the background:

```
#simplemodal-overlay {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Also include the CSS class for displaying the [close image](http://simplemodal.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.3/test/img/x.png) detailed in the instructions:

```
#simplemodal-container a.modalCloseImg {
    background:url(/img/x.png) no-repeat; /* adjust url as required */
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesnt work :( ... It still displays as a mere text. Not as a pop-up

Comment: If you can, post more of your Javascript/HTML so we can see it in context.